# After Isotope Insert, ReLayout

Tags: jquery-isotope

Hi I'm using Isotope with some images. My images are various sizes, ranging from squares to panoramic images that fill the full width of the container.

I was wondering how I could have isotope reLayout the images after insertion of new images, since I do not want large, ugly gaps between my photos.

Here is my code that isn't working

```
function( newElements ) {
      $container.isotope( 'insert', $( newElements ), function(){
        $container.isotope( 'reLayout'); 
      }); 
    }
```

Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$container.append($( newElements )).isotope('insert', $( newElements ));
```